# How to use an USB digitizer?

Tags: tablet, graphics-tablet

i am in China now, and when i saw an USB digitizer (resistive), i bought it, thinking that i could be used as a mouse.
When i connect it to my windows 7 rc1 laptop, the system properties says "pen input available"
But, nothing happens when i touch the panel...

i installed the bundled drivers, in chinese only, and NOT in unicode (so the text is garbled)
When i install the driver, i get access to a special key on the tablet, "switch from pen input to mouse", and the driver will move the pointer according to the position on the tablet. (but no click)
If i use the "pen mode", the computer will use a special chinese IME that is very awkard, i want to use the microsoft ime, and be able to draw/take notes on the screen

There are "generic" drivers? Or just a plain mouse driver that will click when i press on the surface
The tablet name is "qiancai"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to give that cheap digitizer away, and take a wacom digitizer...

There was no way to get it work correctly, it was more than a touchpad than a digitizer